# How to specify xml output for nose programatically

Tags: python, nose

I am running tests from a script with Nose.  I want to be able to specify the xunit xml output file.  The documentation says I can do it with the --xunit-file=FILE option.

I have

```
noseargs = ['--with-xunit', '--xunit-file=output.xml', '--tests=mytest']
nose.run(argv=noseargs)
```

After running this, the output.xml file isn't there.  I've found if I swap the two arguments so it looks like:

```
noseargs = ['--xunit-file=output.xml', '--with-xunit', '--tests=mytest']
nose.run(argv=noseargs)
```

it will create a nosetests.xml file in my working directory.  So it looks like the --with-xunit argument needs to be processed first, then the file needs to be specified.  Is there something particular about how the file should be specified that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nose eats the first argument of argv because on the commandline it's the name of the program.

This works with:

```
noseargs = ['foo', '--with-xunit', '--xunit-file=output.xml', '--tests=mytest']
nose.run(argv=noseargs)
```